# pivot_longer tibble involving NaN, NA, numeric(0)

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to convert a tibble to a longer format.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
  a_X_values = list(numeric(0), c(3, NaN), c(4, 5, 6, NaN, NaN)),
  a_Y_values = list(5, NaN, numeric(0)),
  b_X_values = c(7, 8, 9),
  b_Y_values = c(NA, NaN, 1)
)

tbl_longer <- tbl %>% 
  unnest(where(is.list)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c("alpha", "beta", ".value"), names_sep = "_")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: In row 3, can't recycle input of size 5 to size 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How do I fix the error?

1. It should involve unnesting selected columns which are lists
   `unnest(where(is.list))`
2. A possible solution should also include converting all numeric(0) and NaN to NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be with the empty numeric values that are contained in lists,
if they weren't listed your data.frame wouldn't work

If we apply a function over the list, searching for empty numeric values,
replacing them with NA we can then use your code to pivot longer

```r
library(dplyr)

tbl %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.list), \(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, list(NA), list(x)))) %>% 
  unnest(where(is.list)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c("alpha", "beta", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
  alpha beta  values
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 a     X         NA
 2 a     Y          5
 3 b     X          7
 4 b     Y         NA
 5 a     X          3
 6 a     Y        NaN
 7 b     X          8
 8 b     Y        NaN
 9 a     X        NaN
10 a     Y        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain "|>".

Comment: It's just Base R pipe. If you go to Tools > Global Options > Code you can then click on the check box to use that pipe instead of the one provided by dplyr

Comment: I got errors. tbl |> 
Error: unexpected '>' in "tbl |>"

Comment: Try again, I used the dplyr pipe in the update

Comment: No sir, I am still getting error

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247138/discussion-between-sih-and-jahi-zamy).

Comment: `|>` is new to R 4.0. If you are running R < 4.0 you will encounter errors while trying to call it

Comment: Thanks @GiulioCentorame. I made a small change but I got stuck again. Here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296957/pivot-longer-tibble-involving-nan-na-numeric0-follow-up-question

Comment: This answer still misses a `library(dplyr)` call at the beginning, which is why it probably doesn't work for you